Woman has affair with married man and blamed for wife's death
Trying to find name of this movie
In the movie there is a woman who says she got out of a relationship with a bad guy.  She falls in love with this man who is married and they have an affair. she starts pretending to be in a relationship but the guy continues to try and get away from her.  The wife of the man ends up dying and he states that the Woman did it.  They put the woman under a lie detector or a truth serum and she doesnt say that she kills the wife.  She says instead that her and the guy had a wonderful relationship and the cops are convinced that the man killed the wife when he didnt. 

Elements sound like Fatal Attraction (1987) but the death of the wife doesn't fit

I have a possible match in mind, but could you please add details like approximate year and language\country?

Sounds like a movie I've been searching for for a while. The one I was looking for was called "A Clean Kill".

The question is a bit bare at the moment, but The Deadly Look of Love (AKA Mine Forever) from 2000 might be it. From an online synopsis:

The Deadly Look of Love is a junior version of Fatal Attraction. The young heroine of this film is caught up in her fantasies, the glamorous fantasies of women's magazines, soap operas, sentimental romantic love. She focuses her attention on men at her workplace, is introduced to a man from Chicago, forms an attachment to him which becomes an obsession. When he finally breaks off the liaison and tells her that he is engaged, her obsession overcomes her and she eventually murders the wife. However, when she is arrested, her seeming innocence makes an impression on many people. She even passes a lie detector test with enough chemicals to cure Alzheimer's, according to one of the lawyers. [Actress] Holland Taylor steals the show as the defence lawyer, turning all the evidence against the man from Chicago. She does it in an highly melodramatic way in the court - which even the judge finds it difficult to interrupt.

Here's a clip with the film's heroine:



